# How to return the value of a key: function() in javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Here is what I have inside a backbone model:

```
defaults: {
    prayer_string: function (){
            var label_val = $("#prayer_type_label").val();
            console.log("Prayer_string returning: ", label_val);
            return label_val;
    }
}
```

But when I access the model like so:

```
var prayerString = model.prayer_string;
```

prayerString is the function and not the return label_val.

What do I need to do to get the return value of the function instead of the function itself?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: You want to execute the function prayerString = model.prayer_string(); But I should add that by putting prayer_string on the default hash, you're adding it to the attributes hash of the model. If you want to access this method directly, put it in the list of methods you extend the model with.

Comment: You need to call the function, so `var prayerString = model.prayer_string();`.

Comment: Wouldn't `model.get('prayer_string')` get you the return value? I'm assuming that you're just looking for the value, and don't want it changed dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var yourModel = new (Backbone.Model.extend({
    prayer_string: function () {
        var label_val = $('#prayer_type_label').val();
        console.log('Prayer_string returning: ' + label_val); // use + for concatenating strings
        return label_val;
    }
});

var prayerString = yourModel.prayer_string(); // invoke the method with ()
```